# how to check if a path is actual or symbolic link

Tags: unix, symlink

I am writing my own shell program. I am currently implementing the cd command using chdir.
I want to implement the cd with the below options :

- `-P`    Do not follow symbolic links
- `-L`    Follow symbolic links (default)

When a given path is entered on the shell, how to figure out if the path is a symbolic link or an absolute path progamatically?

Thanks

Comment: Both Unknown and zed_0xff are correct because your question is posed oddly. In a shell script you use the `test` command (a.k.a. `[`) if you are **writing** a shell, you use `stat()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [lstat()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) function , you need to use S_ISLNK on the st_mode field.

Comment: I think you mean `lstat()`, `stat()` will follow the symlink

Answer (score 3):

```
if [ -L /path/to/file ]; then
  echo "is a symlink!"
else
  echo "not a symlink! maybe a directory or regular file, or does not exist"
end
```